# RSS to JSON, YQL

Tags: javascript, json, rss, yql

I'm converting RSS to JSON with yql, with [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20%2a%20from%20feed%20where%20url=%22http://www.vamoosevacations.com/rss/catalog/special/store_id/1/cid/0/%22) query. Now, what's irritating me is that I get the text response just fine (see [this](http://pastie.org/2182095) for a small part of it), but, when I try to parse it with `eval()` (its trusted code), it chokes and says `Unexpected token ":"`. Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: If you are using JSON not JSONP with yql aren't you going to hit cross site scripting issues?

Comment: PHonegap doesn't have restrictions.

Comment: Can you post or link to the whole of the json?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse JSON with eval - see [this article](http://www.json.org/js.html) for more information

You can parse JSON using Douglas Crockford's JSON functions which can be downloaded from [github here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js). This should solve any eval headaches.

So, download json2.js from the above github page. Include it in your page like this:

`<script src="json2.js"></script>`

and then parse your JSON string using:

`var myJsonObject = JSON.parse(myJsonString);`